# How to prevent texstudio from eating indentation;

Tags: texlive, texstudio, editors

When I paste something from other places,texstudio will eat the indentation.

I feel really sad. I use utf8 coding. Can I use some way prevent it from eating indentation?

For example

> original text is:
>
> ```
>    a
> ```
>
> texstudio will get
>
> a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the preferences (options->preferences) and choose the editor tab:

http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01

Then change the  indentation mode.